# iPad 4.3 simulator show black screen with xcode 4.3.3

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode4.3

I have recently updated my Xcode to 4.3.3 and I'm trying to run my old iPad project using the iPad 4.3 simulator, but it shows only a black screen. However this is working correctly on the iPad 5.1 simulator and iPad device which has iOS 5.1. Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try resetting the iOS Simulator by selecting `iPhone Simulator > Reset Content and Settings`

Or even try by completely removing the iOS Simulator by removing the folder iPhone Simulator

```
~/Library/Application Support/
```

The delete the derived data of your Xcode project and restart Xcode (and hope it gets back to live)
Otherwise try it again but also restart the computer

Try setting the Debugger of your scheme to none

```
Product->Edit Scheme->(Select the run Scheme)->Debugger->None
```

Comment: yeah. it's displaying attaching and running too.

Comment: Hay, It's started to work once I changed the Build configuration "Debug" to Release

Answer (score 0):

"Try resetting the iOS Simulator by selecting iPhone Simulator > Reset Content and Settings" solved the issue for me.